# Flood fill in GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Right now I'm working on a simple paint-like program using WinForms and GDI+ and I've approached a simple problem:

I'm using a panel as my canvas.
I'm keeping all my drawable object (shapes, lines and whatnot) in a list. Everytime GDI+ wants to redraw stuff, it iterates through that list, calling Draw() on each object. This method worked great for me: it's fast, looks good, everytime I want the Undo() operation I just ignore the last element from the list when redrawing etc.

The problem is, now I want to add a Flood Fill functionality. How should I approach that problem? First of all, most of the FloodFill implementations I've found works with bitmaps - I don't have a bitmap, all my objects are kept in memory. Should I just draw them on that bitmap? In such case, what then? I can't see a way to manage undo/redo operations anymore. I don't know what to with redrawing.

I'm stuck, I really count on any help, because I suspect that I'm thinking the wrong way here.

Comment: This is vague.  If you want to flood-fill a shape then you simply draw it with Graphics.FillXxx instead of Graphics.DrawXxx.  If you want to fill an area that's bounded by multiple lines then you should turn it into a GraphicsPath and draw it with Graphics.FillPath().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you keep a list of drawable objects (shapes, lines and whatnot).

Well, assuming you implement flood fill, what is the resulting object you wish to get?
The way I see it, it is either a `Bitmap`, or a polygon (array of `Point`).

Because flood fill algorithms operate on bitmaps, you can draw all your current objects onto a temporary buffer `Bitmap`, and then do flood fill on this bitmap. The resulting fill area can either be saved to a `Bitmap`, or using other algorithms, traced back to a polygon (or series of polygons).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Vector_implementations

Comment: Tracing back to a polygon is pretty interesting, however I don't know if it's not an overkill. Let's say I will use a bitmap (I will be drawing directly on panel.backgroundImage), instead of keeping all the objects in a list - is it a good solution? It seems like application's RAM usage is going up pretty fast this way, I'm not sure why.

Comment: this is pretty ugly code (also not seperated from the view), but this is because I'm experimenting right now: [link](http://pastebin.com/n2wdqnuy)

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing, but I can see immediately your memory leak comes from not disposing your bitmap. You are allocating a new bitmap every draw cycle.

Comment: Yes, I am, however I am also disposing panel.BackgroundImage - and this is where this newly allocated bitmap is assigned.

Comment: try unlocking the bits you are locking with `Bitmap.LockBits`